# Is this heteroskedasticity or a cautionary tale about arbitrary p-values or...?

Tags: p-value, linear-model, interpretation, heteroscedasticity

As a sandbox experiment trying to conceptually mimic the following finding from [a paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2981137/)

> A higher incidence of early risk factors accounted for racial differences related to any juvenile arrest, as well as differences in violence- and theft-related arrests. However, increased exposure to early risk factors did not explain race differences in drug-related arrests.

let us consider the following data set (in R):

`x         y
1   1  1.000000
2   2  2.000000
3   3  3.000000
4   4  4.000000
5   5  5.000000
6   6  6.000000
7   7  7.000000
8   8  8.000000
9   9  9.000000
10 10 10.000000
11  1  5.028417
12  2  7.329881
13  3  6.759483
14  4  5.022186
15  5  2.098116
16  6  2.603654
17  7  5.879392
18  8  5.518071
19  9  6.492925
20 10  6.638523`

the second half of which was generated by `rnorm(10,5,3)`, and which overall looks like this:

[image]

This dataset seems to [re]produce the "paradox" from the paper well enough, because while second-half subset yield a non-significant regression fit:

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.2223 -0.2383  0.2950  1.1233  2.1095 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)  5.15365    1.26463   4.075  0.00356 **
x            0.03335    0.20381   0.164  0.87409   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.851 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.003335,  Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1212 
F-statistic: 0.02677 on 1 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.8741
```

the combined dataset yields a significant one

```
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.0732 -1.1432 -0.2372  1.4106  3.7197 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)   2.5768     0.9256   2.784  0.01225 * 
x             0.5167     0.1492   3.463  0.00277 **
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.916 on 18 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3999,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3666 
F-statistic:    12 on 1 and 18 DF,  p-value: 0.002772
```

So how would you best describe this phenomenon where an independent variable is a good explanatory one for a sizeable part of the data, but not for the remainder? You can obviously [spin this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics) result to fit your [prior bias](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/12258/has-the-war-on-drugs-disproportionately-affected-minority-communities/40057#comment167004_40057).

Comment: Could you clarify what is surprising here? One could make a philosophical argument that this is true of most statistical analyses. E.g. not all smokers develop lung cancer - more likely, smoking has an effect only in subgroups that are already frail because of genetic factors, bad health status, environment... We just don't know exactly _which_ subgroups are those, and thus have to rely on marginal effects.

Comment: @juod: I don't find it surprising. As I was typing my "replication" experiment in R I was 95% convinced I'd get what I've got in the end. I'm mainly asking how is phenomenon usually called? "All statistics works like this"?

Comment: I see. In biostatistics, a likely phrasing for such results would be "_x_ interacts with _group_", or "the effect of _x_ is moderated by _group_", where _group_ is some variable identifying those two strata. (See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moderation_(statistics)). I'm not aware if other fields have a more general term for this though.

Comment: This seems to be very much like Simpson's paradox.